# Add new record in primefaces datatable and setfocus

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I want to add a new record in primefaces datatable on clck action. Also i must open the new row in edit mode.
I am able to achieve this by using below code.

Html:

```
<p:commandLink
                            actionListener="#{myBean.addRecord}"
                             update="myDatatable" 
                            oncomplete="jQuery('#myForm\\:myDatatable .ui-datatable-data > tr').first().find('span.ui-icon-pencil').click();
                            ">
<p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/add.jpg"  width="25"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Managed Bean:

```
public void addRecord(){

        if(getMyList() != null) {
            getMyList().add(0, new SisTestReportDetail());
        }
    }
```

I tried doing as shown below,but not working.

```
jQuery('#myForm\\:myDatatable .ui-datatable-data >` tr').first().focus();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in onComplete

```
oncomplete="jQuery('#myForm\\:myDatatable .ui-datatable-data > tr').first()
            .find('span.ui-icon-pencil').click();
jQuery('#myForm\\:myDatatable .ui-datatable-data > tr')
             .first().find('.ui-inputfield').first().focus();">
```